# Connect remotely to security camera system

Tags: vpn, remote-access, portforwarding, recorder, local-network

I would like to connect to a camera security system remotely.

It is set up as such :

1/ There is a recorder (Dahua). The recorder is connected to the local network.
On the local network (using a switch and ethernet) I can connect to the camera by entering the following line in vlc (for instance) rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.42:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1
--> channel number is the camera number.
BUT : I cannot connect remotely.

2/ What's weird : There is a software that comes with that recorder : on the computer it is Smart PSS and on smartphone it is DMSS or iDMSS. Using username, password and device serial number we can access remotely the cameras. The security camera company calls it a p2p camera system.

I don't understand how they can connect remotely without port forwarding.
I would like to know the most secure way to establish a remote connexion to the cameras. It seems there is a way by port forwarding the recorder. (https://www.cctvcameraworld.com/port-forwarding-for-dvr-and-nvr/)
Is it safe?  What do you recommend? And how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it few years ago, the cameras were in EUA and were recording in Mexico with a NVR. you should be able to do it with a public IP connected to the camera and the right ports and network configuration (Make sure that router don't blocks remote connections).
In my case the cameras were connected to a router with a aircard and simcard that provides a public static IP